# JavaFX - Add a Listener to a Pane to check if it is showing

Tags: properties, javafx, listener, javafx-8, show

I am working on JavaFX the last couple of months. I am trying to find a way to implement a listener that is fired whenever a particular pane is shown on the root pane/scene. In Java, I could implement this using the ancestorListener on JPanel as shown below, but I cannot find the equivalent method on JavaFX.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel ();
panel.addAncestorListener ( new AncestorListener ()
{
    public void ancestorAdded ( AncestorEvent event ) {
        System.out.println("This panel is shown on screen now");
    }

    public void ancestorRemoved ( AncestorEvent event ){}

    public void ancestorMoved ( AncestorEvent event ){}
} );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can observe the `sceneProperty()`. This will tell you if the pane (or any other node) is part of a scene graph:

```
pane.sceneProperty().addListener((obs, oldScene, newScene) -> {
    if (newScene == null) {
        // not showing...
    } else {
        // showing ...
    }
});
```

If you want to go further, and see if the pane is part of a scene graph that is in a window that is showing, you can use [EasyBind](https://github.com/TomasMikula/EasyBind):

```
EasyBind.select(pane.sceneProperty())
    .select(Scene::windowProperty)
    .select(Window::showingProperty)
    .orElse(false)
    .addListener((obs, wasShowing, isNowShowing) -> {
         if (isNowShowing) {
             // pane is showing in a window...
         } else {
             // pane is not showing in a window...
    });
```